# Login Redirect - Multiple Scenarios

Tags: redirect, login, customization

I'm trying to create some code that will accomplish the following:

1. If login from any page in this array(example-page-one, example-page-two, example-page-three){
   then, simply refresh the page
2. } elseif login from 'example-page-four' {
   then, redirect to 'payment-page'
3. } elseif login from all other pages {
   then redirect to '/member-account'
   }

So far, all I've accomplished is pulling out my hair.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have very limited coding skills here.  This is what I've cobbled together so far to test, but it doesn't work:

```
function custom_user_login_redirect($redirect_url) {

$page = str_replace('/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);


switch($page) {
    case 'example-page-one':
        return site_url('/example-page-one');
        break;

    default:
        return site_url('/member-account');
        break;
}
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'custom_user_login_redirect' );
```

I know this code won't get me to all three requirements above, but I figured if I could at least get this to work, I might have a shot at getting the rest of it.  Help!

Comment: `var_dump` the value of `$page`, `$redirect_url`, and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to see what you are comparing, then use `die()` to kill the request before the redirect happens. That will help debug a little. (edit and post the results if you can't figure it out). FYI, you'll need to return the value of `$redirect_url` at the bottom of that function to ensure the login redirect filter continues working elsewhere.